# Angular 'reject' is undefined error in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the reject is undefined error in my angular controller and I can not figure out why. This is the method. I added all libraries that are required.
Thank you in advance if you need more information let me know

```
function getUsers() {
    return $http.get('../Admin/GetUsers/').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function failureCallback(response) {
            reject("Error!");
        });
}
```

Comment: Well, `reject` isn't defined anywhere in your code, so...

Comment: The promise is *already* rejected by the time your second callback function is called, what are you trying to do in that second callback?

Comment: Try just "console.log" instead of "reject". For better understanding try https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ and other helpful, resources in Promise.

Comment: I am trying to do the following but with data from the database: https://plnkr.co/edit/cpmUphuLjZOyUxEMvRQ1?p=preview

Comment: @user6440175: Your question's content must be here, on-site. Does the answer below clear things up for you? If not, edit the question to say what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `reject` defined in your code, so naturally trying to use it as a function will fail with a `ReferenceError`.

The promise returned by `$http.get` has *already* been rejected by the time your second handler has been called. Consequently, you probably don't want to handle rejections at all:

```
function getUsers() {
    return $http.get('../Admin/GetUsers/').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
}
```

If you want to handle the rejection but still have the promise from `getUsers` rejected, you need to either throw in your handler or return a promise that is or will be rejected:

```
function getUsers() {
    return $http.get('../Admin/GetUsers/').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function failureCallback(err) { // Note it's an error, not a response
            // Do something here, then
            throw err;
        });
}
```

If you are *handling* the failure and converting it into a success, you'd do that by returning a value to use (or a promise that will ultimately resolve with the value to use) instead of the value from `get`:

```
function getUsers() {
    return $http.get('../Admin/GetUsers/').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function failureCallback(err) { // Note it's an error, not a response
            // Do something here, then
            return valueToUseInstead;
        });
}
```

...but I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. There is not a reject error anymore. but my code still errors out: "TypeError: Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference" . How can I modify my code to work: plnkr.co/edit/cpmUphuLjZOyUxEMvRQ1?p=preview

Comment: @user6440175: As I said above, the content of questions must be **here**, not just linked. But moreover, questions on SO are not meant to be moving targets. If this addresses your question about `reject` being undefined, then it's the answer to the question you asked. If you have another question, then after doing appropriate research, post a new question with the full details ***in*** the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.Either entire method in controller or use service to return rejected value that you want.

```
function getUsers() {
var res=$http.get('../Admin/GetUsers/');
res.success(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
   res.error(function(){ 
        alert("failure");

    });
}
```

Or

Controller.js:

```
function getUsers() {
userService.getAll().then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function(response) { 
        alert(response);   
    });
}
```

Service.js

```
this.getAll = function() {
    var d = $q.defer();
     res.success(function (data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    });
   res.error(function(data){ 
        d.reject(data);

    });
    }
```

Insert '$q' in service.

I've seen plunker. I don't understand what you searching for.
This is error free plunker.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nLR2Eu5pdzEtybPgBke6?p=preview) 
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to search first name. Your version returns not match all the time